# SQL Server 2008: how to give a value of a field in a column and return the column identity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that updates my table data.

```
update tbl_duty
set Name = @DName,
    Necessity = @DNecessity,
    Payment = @DPayment,
    [Estimation Time] = @DEstimationTime,
    Term = @DTerm,
    [Description] = @DDescription
where 
    Id = "what can I put here"
```

but I don't now how get the `ID` of column to update because it generated itself (`identity` column)

Anyone can help me?

Do we have something like `GETIDENTITY(column name)`?

Comment: Are you sure you want an update query and not an insert query?

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610509/getting-the-id-of-a-row-i-updated-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks but No. It was For after Update. I want it before my updating process!

Comment: Yes i know that. is ID!

Comment: Somehow you have to identify the record you want to update.  From where are you sending the other parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
update tbl_duty
set Name = @DName,
    Necessity = @DNecessity,
    Payment = @DPayment,
    [Estimation Time] = @DEstimationTime,
    Term = @DTerm,
    [Description] = @DDescription
where id = (select max(id) from tbl_duty);
```

This seems *very* dangerous.  Why wouldn't you insert the records with the right values in the first place?

Comment: how can i get the right values. the id generated itself. i don't have it