# Get the Identity of Last Updated Row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

`@@IDENTITY` returns the `ID` of the last row **inserted**, I want to retrieve the ID of the last row **updated**.

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE [Table] 
SET Active = 1, 
    Subscribed = 1, 
    RenewDate = GETDATE(),
    EndDate = DATEADD(mm,1,getdate()),
WHERE SC = @SC
  AND Service = @Ser
```

How do I get the ID of this updated row?

The column is called `TableID` and I'm not using it in the query.

Comment: How about firing a select with the same where clause?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot retrieve an ID since there is no ID being inserted.....

But you can:

1. just query the table using the same criteria as in your `UPDATE`:

   ```
   SELECT TableID 
   FROM dbo.Table
   WHERE SC = @SC AND Service = @Ser  -- just use the same criteria
   ```
2. use the `OUTPUT` clause on the `UPDATE` to get that info:

   ```
   UPDATE [Table] 
   SET Active = 1, 
       Subscribed = 1, 
       RenewDate = GETDATE(),
       EndDate = DATEADD(mm,1,getdate())
   OUTPUT Inserted.TableId       -- output the TableID from the table
   WHERE SC = @SC AND Service = @Ser
   ```

[Read more about the `OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) on Technet - it can be used on `INSERT` and `DELETE` as well

Comment: Great post & it helped me out a lot.  It is odd that the Microsoft T-SQL "property" is named _Inserted_ though because an update actually runs.  My point here is that I created a Stored Proc & I need the value of the updated value & then later (under maintenance) someone will see that i'm doing OUTPUT Inserted.[FieldName] & it's not readily apparent that this is actually the value which was updated.

Comment: @raddevus: well - one *could* argue that an `UPDATE` really could be a `delete` on the old data (therefore, that's available in `Deleted`), and then an `insert` of the new data (thus that being available in `Inserted`). It's not done that way - but might be a mental model to understand what those pseudo tables are called ....

Comment: That is very interesting. Thanks for making that point.   You made me think more deeply about what is really going on.

Answer (score 7):

you can try using this:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.TableID
```

in your code it would look like this:

```
    UPDATE [Table] 
    SET Active = 1, 
        Subscribed = 1, 
        RenewDate = GETDATE(),
        EndDate = DATEADD(mm,1,getdate())
OUTPUT INSERTED.TableID 
    WHERE SC = @SC
      AND Service = @Ser
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that there is no comma before OUTPUT

Answer (score 4):

I guess you need this one,

```
UPDATE [Table] 
SET Active = 1, 
    Subscribed = 1, 
    RenewDate = GETDATE(),
    EndDate = DATEADD(mm,1,getdate())
    OUTPUT INSERTED.TABLE_PrimaryKeyID
WHERE SC = @SC
AND Service = @Ser
```

Main source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610509/getting-the-id-of-a-row-i-updated-in-sql-server)

Answer (score -1):

Try using 
select @@identity gives last updated identity for the particular session 
(or)
select scope_identity gives last updated identity for the particular scope 
(or)
select ident_curr('tablename') give the last updated identity regardless of the session or scope but for that particular table.