# Multi-Threaded VB.net: Update then return row id?

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm trying to code a multi-threaded program using VB.NET. It's a simple program: go to a database, get a row, process some back-end, then update the row and set it as "processed = true". Because there is so much data, I'm planning to do a multi-threaded program for it.

SELECT... FOR UPDATE doesn't seem to work in a transaction for some odd reason, and so I've decided to pre-emptively mark the row as "being read = TRUE", then process it from there.

Is it possible to update the row, then retrieve the row ID from the same SQL statement?

I've tried using these SQL statements together:

```
Dim sqlUpdateStatement As String = "SET @uid := 0;UPDATE process_data SET reading = TRUE, idprocess_data = (SELECT @uid := idcrawl_data) WHERE reading IS NOT TRUE AND processed IS NOT TRUE LIMIT 1;SELECT @uid;"
```

but it tells me that there was a fatal error encountered during command execution.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

After some testing, I've come to the conclusion that you can't use MySQL variables when performing updates in VB.Net. Is this true? And if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: This should be done in a store procedure. Maybe think of it a different way, instead of selecting 1 at a time. Select all that need modification and send that list to your thread and let it process. When it's done, get a new list of id to modify.

Comment: I think you may have to resort to using a `for update trigger` and getting the Id from the `Inserted` table inside the trigger. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610530/9365244) seems similar to yours, with the answer being related to a Trigger

Comment: @the_lotus the backend demands that the processing is done row by row though...

Comment: You should use a stored procedure .....

Comment: "Because there is so much data, I'm planning to do a multi-threaded program for it." - That's not really good reason. If you said "Because there is so much **CPU-based computation**, I'm planning to do a multi-threaded program for it." then you'd be on a winner. With lots of data you need lots of bandwidth - multithreading doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually took the time to debug the SELECT FOR UPDATE portion of my code to get it to work on a Transaction basis. Thanks everyone for their time!